# Command in .zshrc not found

Tags: shell, rubygems, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), I've got the following at the bottom of `.zshrc`:

```
fortune | xargs -0 cowsay | lolcat -a
```

When run from `.zshrc`, it complains:

```
/Users/jorum/.zshrc:59: command not found: lolcat
```

Running it manually from the command line works:

```
➜  ~  fortune | xargs -0 cowsay | lolcat -a  
<insert colorful cow saying something insightful here>
```

Leaving `lolcat -a` out entirely also works (sans the colors of course).

Clearly, `lolcat` isn't missing:

```
➜  ~  gem list lolcat
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
lolcat (42.0.99)
```

Why does it not work if executed from within `.zshrc`?

Comment: lolcat is probably not in the PATH. Tried to prefix it with full path? Since it's ruby gem, the executable might be stored in some uncommon directory.

Comment: @tvm `echo $PATH` reveals that it is indeed in PATH. `/Users/jorum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/jorum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/jorum/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/jorum/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` (using RVM). I can run `lolcat` manually from outside `.zshrc`.

Comment: The directory that contains `lolcat` is being added to the path after you try to it, probably later in `.zshrc` or in a file source from `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the line in question to `.zlogin` fixed the problem.

More specifically, I had to move it below this line that was added by RVM:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`